# Android: Icono de searchview no aparece en mi toolbar

Tags: android, searchview

Estoy tratando de poner mi icono de searchview en dos vistas, por ejemplo en A y B, el problema es que no aparece en la primer vista (A), pero el searchview si aparece en mi vista (B) estoy usando exactamente el mismo código que emplee en la vista que si funciona claramente cambiando el nombre de algunas variables para que no cause conflicto, pero no estoy realmente seguro porque no aparece en la otra.

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".ManageFragments.MainActivity">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:title="@string/action_search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

**Search_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/GrayBackground"
    tools:context=".HomeFragments.SearchFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: vas por buen camino, ya agregaste el menu en la acitiivdas

Comment: Podrías agregar el layout de la vista A y B que comentas?

Answer (score 0):

tiene que inflar el menu o añadirlo de esta forma:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

   }
```